# HTML Spoiler Not Working Properly (JS and CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I've got this problem with a spoiler... i found it on the web and it looked very exciting to implement in my website, but now I'm having problems with it. I think that the JS isn't working properly, because the HTML works but it lacks the functions of the spoiler.

Anyway, this is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
<div class="toggle">
    <div class="open">
        <img src="http://www.abload.de/img/plus6jcm3.png" alt="">
        <a href="#">Open Spoiler</a>
    </div>
    <div class="close" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://www.abload.de/img/minuswfdlk.png" alt="">
        <a href="#">Close Spoiler</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content" style="display:none;">Spoiler content</div>
</div>
```

And the one I'm having problems with... 
JS

```
// Expand Panel
$(".open").click(function(){
    $(".content").slideDown("fast", function() {
       $(".content").animate({"height": "+=5px", }, "fast");
       $(".content").animate({"height": "-=5px", }, "fast");
    });
    $(".open").hide();
    $(".close").show();
});


// Collapse Panel
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".content").animate({"height": "+=10px", }, "fast");
    $(".content").slideUp("fast", function() {
       $(".content").animate({"height": "-=10px", }, "fast");
       $(".close").hide();
       $(".open").show();
    });
});
```

I've used Javascript some times before, but this is unlike anything I've ever seen. I've tried to put it in many different ways.. but it hasn't worked. This is what I have now, and it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Expand Panel
    $(".open").click(function(){
        $(".content").slideDown("fast", function() {
           $(".content").animate({"height": "+=5px", }, "fast");
           $(".content").animate({"height": "-=5px", }, "fast");
        });
        $(".open").hide();
        $(".close").show();
    });


    // Collapse Panel
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".content").animate({"height": "+=10px", }, "fast");
        $(".content").slideUp("fast", function() {
           $(".content").animate({"height": "-=10px", }, "fast");
           $(".close").hide();
           $(".open").show();
        });
    });
</script>
<link href="<default/spoiler.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
<div class="panel">
<div class="toggle">
    <div class="open">
        <img src="http://www.abload.de/img/plus6jcm3.png" alt="">
        <a href="#">Open Spoiler</a>
    </div>
    <div class="close" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://www.abload.de/img/minuswfdlk.png" alt="">
        <a href="#">Close Spoiler</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content" style="display:none;">Spoiler content</div>
</div>
```

Is this a problem I'm having or is this script broken? How should I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you animating content's height with `+=5px` and `-=5px` right after each other?

Comment: @meagar, otherwise it droops too low and doesn't come back up fast enough

Comment: What's not working?  Here's a cut-and-paste into JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kYrf9/

Comment: @psquared yeah I know it works, but I'm stuck on how to put it all together

Comment: The issue is that is not fast enought?

Comment: @Florin no, it's that I don't know how to put all the code together ;(

Comment: "puting the code together" not sure what you mean. Just make sure the javascript code is loading after jquery.js and everything should be OK.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/coscho/wc9WM/2/ here is working just fine

Comment: @Florin yeah it works fine on jsfiddle, but for some reason it doesn't on my website. is the code I posted in the first post all right?

Comment: Yes everyting is ok. Check if you have errors in your other js files. This could be also a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated ;)

Make sure you have jQuery on your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Insert this before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
$(".spoiler .toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() == "+| Show") {
        $(this).text("-| Hide");
    } else {
        $(this).text("+| Show");
    }
});
</script>
```

Then, wherever you want a spoiler:

```
<div class="spoiler">
    <div class="toggle">+| Show</div>
    <div class="content" style="display:none"><hr />
        CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kYrf9/13/

Comment: i think i'm going to give up. I know this works, but it's not working for me, maybe it's my host.